# Sudo without password on remote machine

Tags: ssh, remote-access, sudo

I have a large cluster with password-less ssh login set up using public keys.

Now I want to be able to run commands like so

```
ssh -l username -i path-to-key-file remote host 'sudo command'
```

Ideally I'd have liked to even parallelize this over my cluster instead of sequentially in a for-loop, but so far, I can't even get this basic one-remote-host thing to work.

I've tried the following without success. Any ideas? Note that using a password is not an option.

```
ssh -t ...
ssh -t -t ...
```

Comment: It turned out that sudo with "ssh -t -t ..." was working on part of my cluster. The odd thing is that while sudo doesn't work for the rest of the nodes, su -c does (still with ssh -t -t). The nodes all are Fedora 12, and have identical /etc/sudoers. I have no clue why this is happening, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want parallel ssh execution of arbitrary commands, I advise you take a look at:

- fabric http://www.fabfile.org (if you like python) or
- sshkit https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit (if you prefer ruby)

They are both pretty simple.

Comment: Both of those look useful, but I didn't get around to trying them. My code is in neither python, nor ruby. But these seem useful possibly for the future. Apparently, I don't have enough 'reputation' to upvote your answer!

Comment: Your code don't need to be in either pytyhon or ruby. Those tools are made as standalone utilities for remote exec. I'm using Fabric for managing ssh key changes for my users on all my servers at once, for example. Writing a fabfile only involves very little python and mostly uses the DSL that Fabric has defined. Same goes for SSHkit.